# Why does my Ubuntu display a corrupted screen on first boot but then work after rebooting?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am facing a problem, whenever I boot my computer it show distorted display and hangs there only. The distorted display is shown below

[image: distorted display on screen]

I have to power it off through power button and when I power it on again it shows below messages and then boots properly.

[image: Message during second boot]

I am not able to find why am I getting this issue.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but only when I run the Display control panel.

Comment: I also have a similar problem.  I thought it might be that I updated my kernel and needed to rebuild my video driver so I booted into recovery mode and did that.  From recovery mode I can now boot up my desktop by selecting return to normal boot (I can't remember exactly what it says) but just a normal boot does not work. I get a screen like the above :(

Answer (score 1):

This page describes a fix that worked for me: https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for a line that looks something like:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and add the `nomodeset` to the end of it.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub2
```